# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0') discord.js v13 error

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I am getting this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
    at Client.<anonymous> (/home/container/index.js:660:36)
    at Client.emit (node:events:525:35)
    at InteractionCreateAction.handle (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/actions/InteractionCreate.js:83:12)
    at module.exports [as INTERACTION_CREATE] (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/handlers/INTERACTION_CREATE.js:4:36)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketManager.js:346:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:482:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (/home/container/node_modules/discord.js/src/client/websocket/WebSocketShard.js:317:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (/home/container/node_modules/ws/lib/event-target.js:199:18)
    at WebSocket.emit (node:events:513:28)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (/home/container/node_modules/ws/lib/websocket.js:1178:20)
```

This is the code:

```js
client.on('interactionCreate', async (interaction) => {
  if (interaction.isSelectMenu) {
    if (interaction.customId == 'orderselect') {
      //Regular Ticket
      if (interaction.values[0] === 'CLAN') {
        const user = interaction.user.id;
        const claim = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
          new MessageButton()
            .setCustomId('CLAIM')
            .setLabel('Claim the ticket')
            .setStyle('SUCCESS')
            .setEmoji('<a:yes:1032348720181817485>'),
        );
        const ticketOpenmsg = new MessageEmbed()
          .setTitle(
            ' Thanks for ordering a clan server | Please answer the questions below',
          )
          .setDescription(
            `**Dear <@${user}>!**\n\n**Please could you answer these questions:**\n\n> **<a:Right_Arrow_Yellow:1003184037508161536> 1. What do you want the server name to be?**\n> *E.g. Clan Server*\n\n> **<a:Right_Arrow_Yellow:1003184037508161536> 2. What should the server avatar be? If none, state none.**\n> *E.g. cdn.discordapp.com/attachements/.../...*\n\n> **<a:Right_Arrow_Yellow:1003184037508161536> 3. What should the channel design be?**\n> *E.g \` | general\`**\n\n> **<a:Right_Arrow_Yellow:1003184037508161536> 4. What should be the category design?**\n> *E.g. \`CATEGORY\`*\n\n> **<a:Right_Arrow_Yellow:1003184037508161536> 5. What should the roles design be like?**\n> *E.g. OWNER*\n\n> **<a:Right_Arrow_Yellow:1003184037508161536> 6. Are there any special wishes you would like?**\n> *What time would you want the server to be ready*\n\n> **<a:Right_Arrow_Yellow:1003184037508161536> 7. What is the payment method?**\n> *6 invites/1 boost*`,
          );
        const ticketOpenmsg2 = new MessageEmbed()
          .setTitle(
            `<a:loading:1034074800840253510> A Staff Member will claim the Ticket soon!`,
          )
          .setDescription(
            `**Dear <@${user}>!**\n> This Ticket will be claimed by a Staff Member as soon as possible! In the meantime, please answer the questions above.\n\n> *He/She/They will help you then!*\n\n**Meanwhile, make sure to list us all information needed!**`,
          )
          .setFooter(
            'Thanks for choosing ARC | Development ✌️',
            client.user.displayAvatarURL(),
          );
        interaction.guild.channels
          .create(`・clan・${interaction.user.username}`, {
            type: 'GUILD_TEXT',
            parent: '1034817138432684082',
            permissionOverwrites: [
              {
                id: interaction.user,
                allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                deny: ['SEND_MESSAGES'],
              },
              {
                id: interaction.guild.roles.everyone,
                allow: [],
                deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES'],
              },
            ],
          })
          .then((channel) =>
            channel.send({
              content: `<@${interaction.user.id}>\n> Staff Ping: <@&1018937502683385876> | <@&1008051649681571875>`,
              embeds: [ticketOpenmsg, ticketOpenmsg2],
              components: [claim],
            }),
          );
        interaction.reply({
          content: `Succecfully create you ticket!`,
          ephemeral: true,
        });
      }
      // Community Server
      if (interaction.values[0] === 'COMMUNITY') {
        const user = interaction.user.id;
        const claim = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
          new MessageButton()
            .setCustomId('CLAIM')
            .setLabel('Claim the ticket')
            .setStyle('SUCCESS')
            .setEmoji('<a:yes:1032348720181817485>'),
        );
        const ticketOpenmsg = new MessageEmbed()
          .setTitle(
            ' Thanks for ordering a community server | Please answer the questions below',
          )
          .setDescription(
            `**Dear <@${user}>!**\n\n**Please could you answer these questions:**\n\n> **<a:Right_Arrow_Yellow:1003184037508161536> 1. What do you want the server name to be?**\n> *E.g. Clan Server*\n\n> **<a:Right_Arrow_Yellow:1003184037508161536> 2. What should the server avatar be? If none, state none.**\n> *E.g. cdn.discordapp.com/attachements/.../...*\n\n> **<a:Right_Arrow_Yellow:1003184037508161536> 3. What should the channel design be?**\n> *E.g \` | general\`**\n\n> **<a:Right_Arrow_Yellow:1003184037508161536> 4. What should be the category design?**\n> *E.g. \`CATEGORY\`*\n\n> **<a:Right_Arrow_Yellow:1003184037508161536> 5. What should the roles design be like?**\n> *E.g. OWNER*\n\n> **<a:Right_Arrow_Yellow:1003184037508161536> 6. Are there any special wishes you would like?**\n> *What time would you want the server to be ready*\n\n> **<a:Right_Arrow_Yellow:1003184037508161536> 7. What is the payment method?**\n> *6 invites/1 boost*`,
          );
        const ticketOpenmsg2 = new MessageEmbed()
          .setTitle(
            `<a:loading:1034074800840253510> A Staff Member will claim the Ticket soon!`,
          )
          .setDescription(
            `**Dear <@${user}>!**\n> This Ticket will be claimed by a Staff Member as soon as possible! In the meantime, please answer the questions above.\n\n> *He/She/They will help you then!*\n\n**Meanwhile, make sure to list us all information needed!**`,
          )
          .setFooter(
            'Thanks for choosing ARC | Development ✌️',
            client.user.displayAvatarURL(),
          );
        interaction.guild.channels
          .create(`・community・${interaction.user.username}`, {
            type: 'GUILD_TEXT',
            parent: '1034817434508595230',
            permissionOverwrites: [
              {
                id: interaction.user,
                allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                deny: ['SEND_MESSAGES'],
              },
              {
                id: interaction.guild.roles.everyone,
                allow: [],
                deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES'],
              },
            ],
          })
          .then((channel) =>
            channel.send({
              content: `<@${interaction.user.id}>\n> Staff Ping: <@&1018937502683385876> | <@&1008051649681571875>`,
              embeds: [ticketOpenmsg, ticketOpenmsg2],
              components: [claim],
            }),
          );
        interaction.reply({
          content: `Succecfully create you ticket!`,
          ephemeral: true,
        });
      }
      // Development Server -
      if (interaction.values[0] === 'DEV') {
        const user = interaction.user.id;
        const claim = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
          new MessageButton()
            .setCustomId('CLAIM')
            .setLabel('Claim the ticket')
            .setStyle('SUCCESS')
            .setEmoji('<a:yes:1032348720181817485>'),
        );
        const ticketOpenmsg = new MessageEmbed()
          .setTitle(
            '⚒️ Thanks for ordering a clan server | Please answer the questions below',
          )
          .setDescription(
            `**Dear <@${user}>!**\n\n**Please could you answer these questions:**\n\n> **<a:Right_Arrow_Yellow:1003184037508161536> 1. What do you want the server name to be?**\n> *E.g. Clan Server*\n\n> **<a:Right_Arrow_Yellow:1003184037508161536> 2. What should the server avatar be? If none, state none.**\n> *E.g. cdn.discordapp.com/attachements/.../...*\n\n> **<a:Right_Arrow_Yellow:1003184037508161536> 3. What should the channel design be?**\n> *E.g \` | general\`**\n\n> **<a:Right_Arrow_Yellow:1003184037508161536> 4. What should be the category design?**\n> *E.g. \`CATEGORY\`*\n\n> **<a:Right_Arrow_Yellow:1003184037508161536> 5. What should the roles design be like?**\n> *E.g. OWNER*\n\n> **<a:Right_Arrow_Yellow:1003184037508161536> 6. Are there any special wishes you would like?**\n> *What time would you want the server to be ready*\n\n> **<a:Right_Arrow_Yellow:1003184037508161536> 7. What is the payment method?**\n> *6 invites/1 boost*`,
          );
        const ticketOpenmsg2 = new MessageEmbed()
          .setTitle(
            `<a:loading:1034074800840253510> A Staff Member will claim the Ticket soon!`,
          )
          .setDescription(
            `**Dear <@${user}>!**\n> This Ticket will be claimed by a Staff Member as soon as possible! In the meantime, please answer the questions above.\n\n> *He/She/They will help you then!*\n\n**Meanwhile, make sure to list us all information needed!**`,
          )
          .setFooter(
            'Thanks for choosing ARC | Development ✌️',
            client.user.displayAvatarURL(),
          );
        interaction.guild.channels
          .create(`⚒️・dev・${interaction.user.username}`, {
            type: 'GUILD_TEXT',
            parent: '1034817677664976956',
            permissionOverwrites: [
              {
                id: interaction.user,
                allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
                deny: ['SEND_MESSAGES'],
              },
              {
                id: interaction.guild.roles.everyone,
                allow: [],
                deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES'],
              },
            ],
          })
          .then((channel) =>
            channel.send({
              content: `<@${interaction.user.id}>\n> Staff Ping: <@&1018937502683385876> | <@&1008051649681571875>`,
              embeds: [ticketOpenmsg, ticketOpenmsg2],
              components: [claim],
            }),
          );
        interaction.reply({
          content: `Succecfully create you ticket!`,
          ephemeral: true,
        });
      }
    }
  }
  // Shop Server -
  if (interaction.values[0] === 'SHOP') {
    const user = interaction.user.id;
    const claim = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
      new MessageButton()
        .setCustomId('CLAIM')
        .setLabel('Claim the ticket')
        .setStyle('SUCCESS')
        .setEmoji('<a:yes:1032348720181817485>'),
    );
    const ticketOpenmsg = new MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(
        ' Thanks for ordering a shop server | Please answer the questions below',
      )
      .setDescription(
        `**Dear <@${user}>!**\n\n**Please could you answer these questions:**\n\n> **<a:Right_Arrow_Yellow:1003184037508161536> 1. What do you want the server name to be?**\n> *E.g. Clan Server*\n\n> **<a:Right_Arrow_Yellow:1003184037508161536> 2. What should the server avatar be? If none, state none.**\n> *E.g. cdn.discordapp.com/attachements/.../...*\n\n> **<a:Right_Arrow_Yellow:1003184037508161536> 3. What should the channel design be?**\n> *E.g \` | general\`**\n\n> **<a:Right_Arrow_Yellow:1003184037508161536> 4. What should be the category design?**\n> *E.g. \`CATEGORY\`*\n\n> **<a:Right_Arrow_Yellow:1003184037508161536> 5. What should the roles design be like?**\n> *E.g. OWNER*\n\n> **<a:Right_Arrow_Yellow:1003184037508161536> 6. Are there any special wishes you would like?**\n> *What time would you want the server to be ready*\n\n> **<a:Right_Arrow_Yellow:1003184037508161536> 7. What is the payment method?**\n> *6 invites/1 boost*`,
      );
    const ticketOpenmsg2 = new MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle(
        `<a:loading:1034074800840253510> A Staff Member will claim the Ticket soon!`,
      )
      .setDescription(
        `**Dear <@${user}>!**\n> This Ticket will be claimed by a Staff Member as soon as possible! In the meantime, please answer the questions above.\n\n> *He/She/They will help you then!*\n\n**Meanwhile, make sure to list us all information needed!**`,
      )
      .setFooter(
        'Thanks for choosing ARC | Development ✌️',
        client.user.displayAvatarURL(),
      );
    interaction.guild.channels
      .create(`・shop・${interaction.user.username}`, {
        type: 'GUILD_TEXT',
        parent: '1034817623847862272',
        permissionOverwrites: [
          {
            id: interaction.user,
            allow: ['VIEW_CHANNEL'],
            deny: ['SEND_MESSAGES'],
          },
          {
            id: interaction.guild.roles.everyone,
            allow: [],
            deny: ['VIEW_CHANNEL', 'SEND_MESSAGES'],
          },
        ],
      })
      .then((channel) =>
        channel.send({
          content: `<@${interaction.user.id}>\n> Staff Ping: <@&1018937502683385876> | <@&1008051649681571875>`,
          embeds: [ticketOpenmsg, ticketOpenmsg2],
          components: [claim],
        }),
      );
    interaction.reply({
      content: `Succecfully create you ticket!`,
      ephemeral: true,
    });
  }
});
```

I tried to check if the code was correct and it is but I don't know why I get this error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  Please see [Something in my web site or project doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254428/328193)  Relevant code needs to be included in the question to produce a [mcve] which demonstrates the problem, as well as information about the problem itself and what debugging you have done.  To learn more about this community and how we can help you, please start with the [tour] and read [ask] and its linked resources.

Comment: Having said that... The error implies that you are trying to read an array index (in this case `0`) from `undefined` (which of course isn't an array).

Comment: But how to fix the error? I just don't get it.

Comment: You'd fix it by not trying to reference an element or property from `undefined`.  For example, you can check if a value exists before trying to use it.  This is very generic because we don't know what code is producing the error or what functionality that code is trying to achieve.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because you check `if (interaction.values[0] === 'SHOP')` outside of `if (interaction.isSelectMenu)`. It means that your code tries to check the value of `interaction.values[0]` even if it's not a select menu (when `interaction.values` is `undefined`).

Just move the `if (interaction.values[0] === 'SHOP')` part inside `if (interaction.customId == 'orderselect')` and it will work as expected.